# Jquery Issue in Appending Text to a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I was doing validations for input fields using Jquery by just checking if a value is supplied for the fields or not.

In case there is NO value supplied, I just used to Append Text: "Duration:*Required" to the Field's "Label" controls as:

```
$('label[for="Duration_Value"]').Append(" Duration:* Required");
```

The problem is that for the very first time, if a user doesn't selects a value for the "Duration" dropdown, error message displays fine.

But, again , without selecting any value, if the Submit button is subsequently clicked, the Error Message: "Duration:* Required" keeps adding at end as seen below:

[image]

Which Jquery function shoul be used to change Text / error message displayed so that no matter how many times submit button clicked, Error message don't add up as above ?

Comment: Add a span with the text hidden by default, when you want to show error show the span

Comment: @Tushar: Altering the original HTML in markup (.aspx) is not allowed to me. Let me know more alternatives please

Comment: Okay, then check if the message is already added in the label using `indexOf`

Comment: @Tushar: Any sample code you have ?

Comment: Use the append method to do what Tushar said - thus avoiding editing original markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to check if the message is already added, if not then only add the message to the `label`.

```
if ($('label[for="Duration_Value"]').text().indexOf(" Duration:* Required") === -1) {
    $('label[for="Duration_Value"]').append(" Duration:* Required");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If value is not specified, then call this

```
 $('label[for="Duration_Value"]').text(" Duration:* Required");
```

and if value is specified then clear label text like this

```
$('label[for="Duration_Value"]').text("");
```

Comment: This will remove the previous text of `label` which I guess OP want to preserve

Comment: @Tushar  If he is just trying validation, then I don't think so there is any logic to preserve that value as he is showing only error message not retaining any value